# Wallets vs Addresses

Tags: wallet, address

I dont understand how a wallet comes into play?
Is a wallet a necessary part of a transaction or is it just a way of collating multiple addresses?

I get how I should use a new address for each transaction but don't understand whether they have to be attached to a wallet?

I am looking to generate thousands of addresses to accept payments for purchases in my online shop. Once an address has money in it, do I need to collate all the money together in a central account?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between a wallet and an address?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/13059/whats-the-difference-between-a-wallet-and-an-address)

Answer (score 10):

> Is a wallet a necessary part of a transaction or is it just a way of collating multiple addresses?

Wallets are just a convenient way to store/back up multiple private keys (corresponding to multiple addresses).

> Once an address has money in it, do I need to collate all the money together in a central account?

Not really - you can spend money from multiple addresses in one transaction.

Comment: thanks Nick, how does that work? How would I send from multiple addresses in one transaction, if I don't use a wallet? (We are building a web app, which needs to receive payments and then pay out winnings. (which may be more than the initial payment). Any ideas

Comment: @BitWarrior Is there some reason why you are opposed to using a wallet?

Comment: I don't think you understand what a wallet is.. 
A wallet is simply a way (fileformat) to store multiple addresses in a single file. If you store all addresses in a database, then your .sql file is your "wallet".