# Can I receive different cryptocurrencies on the same public key?

Tags: public-key, currencies

The main question I have is:

**Can I receive different cryptocurrencies on a same public key?**

*For example: I instruct the person A to send me BTC on a public key X. I also instruct the person B to send me XRP (or any other crypto) on the same public key X.*

- If not - can you briefly explain why not, i.e. what prevents it? I've read on few places that this is impossible (not sure if true), but I don't really understand why (if true). What prevents me from doing it? Aren't the block-chains isolated from one another? Also, as far as I know, most (if not all) cryptocurrencies use the same public-private key logic under the hood.
- If yes - are there any specific cons apart from obvious (one basket for all)?

Note: This question does not imply the use of online wallets that may have their own logic of aggregating multiple keys under the same online wallet.

**EDIT:**

> Actually, I think I made a mistake in the premise of my question. We
> don't use public key but address for receiving funds (see link #1). I
> guess I overlooked that part in the analysis. And the addresses have
> differences in prefixes among currencies (see link #2) #1 -
> bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/80708/… #2 -
> blockgeeks.com/guides/blockchain-address-101

Comment: Actually, I think I made a mistake in the premise of my question. We don't use public key but address for receiving funds (see link #1). I guess I overlooked that part in the analysis. And the addresses have differences in prefixes among currencies (see link #2) #1 - https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/80708/what-is-the-difference-between-your-address-and-your-public-keys #2 - https://blockgeeks.com/guides/blockchain-address-101/

Comment: Hi Del Pro, since there haven't been any answers on this topic yet, please feel free to edit your question to update it with your improved understanding. If you are no longer looking for an answer, please vote to close it instead.

Comment: Hello Murch. I don't see the close option from my side (I only see options Share, Edit, Delete, Flag). The question is resolved from my point of view, so please feel free to close it (if you can). Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me, it looks like some other community members have voted to close.